# Can I use RSACryptoServiceProvider public/private keys to interop with Crypto++?

Tags: .net, interop, cryptography, crypto++

I've created a public/private key using [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and saved it as XML. I can use this to encrypt/decrypt/sign and verify data in .NET.

I have another application which is intended to run on a Linux server. I'm developing it in C++ and I'm using Crypto++ for my cryptography needs.

I want to share data between these two applications, but to do that I need to convert the RSAParameters into public/private keys that Crypto++ can understand.

I'm also open to using convert public/private keys generated by Crypto++ into RSAParameters if it is easier to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the RSAParameters directly instead of going over XML.

Just store the byte-arrays contained in the RSAParameters in a file using a format of your own choice. Read the byte-arrays back in your C++ program and create [CryptoPP::Integer](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html)s from them. Use those Integers to Initialize a [RSAFunction](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_r_s_a_function.html) (public key) or [InvertibleRSAFunction](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_invertible_r_s_a_function.html) (private key).

The reverse way is similiar: I.e.

```
RSAFunction publicKey = ...;

size_t modulusLength = publicKey.getModulus().ByteCount();
unsigned char * modulus = new unsigned char[modulusLength];
publicKey.getModulus().Encode(modulus, modulusLength);

// similarly with PublicExponent and remember to clean up the arrays.
```

and transfer the arrays to your .NET-application, where you can use them to initialize an RSAParameters.

Comment: I knew it would be trivially simple for somebody... Just got it working yesterday by packing the private key in the PKCS #8 format and the public key in the X509 format. I think your way would have been easier.